# How do you cut off part of a mesh you don't want?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view

I made a clothing mesh in the program  Sculptris a open source sculpting progam and then exported the mesh to Blender 3d. When I made the mesh in Sculptris I made alot mistakes on the pant leg and I do not like the way it looks  so I want to delete the part of the pant legs and redo it. However,  I do not know how to delete parts of mesh I do not like.  I am still much a newbie to Blender, I understand most the basics of the program but I am still learning all the tools in Blender.  I am sorry this such a newbie question.  Can you please explain it to me of what is the tool to use and how to use it?

Comment: You should probably star by watching some beginner tutorials first

Comment: enter edit mode, select the parts you don't want and press delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to [Edit Mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/modes.html).

You can do this by going to the Tab (Don't know what to call it) near the bottom, most likely called **Object Mode** and clicking it followed by **Edit Mode**. You can also press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, which is the shortcut.

All of the vertices should be selected, which you can tell if they are orange. We don't want all of the vertices selected. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all the vertices, it should go from orange to black.

Now you need to select the area you would like to delete. Press <kbd>B</kbd> and drag over the area desired. Make sure to rotate around the model since it won't select the vertices on the other side (and I don't know how to fix that but it should work either way)

After the vertices of the desired area has been selected press <kbd>X</kbd> and then click 'Vertices'

Hope this helps.

Comment: B is not the only selection tool, though: see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#selection-tools and deselecting the "limit selection to visible" edit mode 3d view setting will make the selection work "on the other side" too...

Answer (score 1):

> Now you need to select the area you would like to delete. Press B and
>   drag over the area desired. Make sure to rotate around the model since
>   it won't select the vertices on the other side (and I don't know how
>   to fix that but it should work either way)

In regard to this issue, I would just add, that to spare yourself from rotating the object all around, go to the front view (on Numpad press <kbd>5</kbd> to change to user Ortho and press <kbd>3</kbd> for the front view).

Then pres <kbd>Z</kbd> that will show your mesh transparent so when you are selecting the vertices from one side using mentioned method (<kbd>B</kbd> than drag), the vertices are going to be selected from both sides.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice mesh in sculpt mode using "Mask Slice and Fill Holes" function.

[image: Mask menu screenshot]

Comment: While this is a valid option, could you please add some more details to your answer how masking would be used?